# How do I return rows if concatenated value is within another set of values?

Tags: sql

This may be a dumb question, but I am trying to concatenate values from two columns and then return rows where those concatenated values are in another set.

My question is, what is the best method to do this?  I've done this in the past using an IN statement, but if I have a lot of values this time around.

Would I be better off creating a new table with my comparison values and get my results using some kind of relationship statement?  Something like that below?

```
SELECT Users.ID + Users.SubID AS UniqueID, TempVals.ID
FROM Users, TempVals
WHERE Users.ID + Users.SubID = TempVals.ID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work fine assuming it's MySQL and the data types of the columns being concatenated are strings/character-types - no worries, you *should* be able to cast them.

Another way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.ID + U.SubID AS UniqueID
FROM Users as U
WHERE (U.ID + U.SubID) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT T.ID
    FROM TempVals as T
)
```

Also, the type of database will determine the method of concatenation:

- SQL Server: +
- Oracle: CONCAT()
- MySQL: CONCAT()

[Reference: Using IN Statement - SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)

Comment: I am using MS Access which appears to be restrictive to standard SQL.  Also, I ran into issues using the field alias in the WHERE clause.  I was told that this is because the WHERE clause is evaluated first.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that when I wrote UniqueID there because it's been a while.  You can try to substitute "... WHERE UniqueID IN ..." with "... (WHERE U.ID + U.SubID) IN..."